# js expression.test(string) - not expected results

Tags: javascript, regex

Been awhile since I needed to do this and I'm just not seeing what the problem is - maybe I'm just burned out too much right now.

```
var url = '/some-test.php?t=a-t!est&f=&c=4564646&u=4546&ds=45646&de=1254';

if( /^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\.\?\=\&]/i.test(url) ) {
    console.log('true');
} else {
    console.log('false');
}
```

Why is this passing true with 't!est' in the string?

My goal here is to make sure the string is only comprised of :

```
a-z
A-Z
0-9
/
-
.
?
=
&
case insensitive
```

I just want to do a quick and simple validation of url (or anything else) before using it... making sure it is only comprised of the characters I specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only matching a single character from your character class. As written, the regex is only matching (successfully) the first `/` and parsing no further. Add a `+` or `*` to the end of character class to match multiple characters in test string. Finally, add `$` to the end of the regex to anchor to end of line and ensure matches match the entire line.

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\.\?\=\&]+$/`

Or

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\.\?\=\&]*$/`

Comment: Yep... tired.  I copied the expression over from using url.match().  Thanks.

Comment: /^[a-z0-9\/\-\.\?\=\&]+$/i.test(url) - $ is needed